# Issue with Xamarin.InAppBilling

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.ios, in-app-billing, monogame

I'm working with the [Xamarin.InAppBilling component](http://components.xamarin.com/view/xamarin.inappbilling), and consistently encountering an error. The problem is with the override method:

```
protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data) {
  // Ask the open service connection's billing handler to process this request
  _serviceConnection.BillingHandler.HandleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

  // Ask the open connection's billing handler to get any purchases
  var purchases = _serviceConnection.BillingHandler.GetPurchases(ItemType.Product);
  foreach (var purchase in purchases) {
    FufillOrder(purchase);
  }
}
```

When using the reserved id `"android.test.purchased"`, [a reserved product string,](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html) This override method works fine, both locally and in the live Beta channel of my application. The method is invoked, and the product is fulfilled.

However with any **live** In-App Products, those populated by a id string:

```
 Products = await _serviceConnection.BillingHandler.QueryInventoryAsync(new List<string> {
          "example",
        }, ItemType.Product);
```

this method is not invoked when the user completes the purchase cycle.

*To further confuse things* - in the Android Merchant Console, the orders were successfully processed, and reported as 'Delivered', so no problem there.

However, the issue remains the same. The following code does not work for **live** products:

```
protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data) {
  // Ask the open service connection's billing handler to process this request
  _serviceConnection.BillingHandler.HandleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

  // Ask the open connection's billing handler to get any purchases
  var purchases = _serviceConnection.BillingHandler.GetPurchases(ItemType.Product);
  foreach (var purchase in purchases) {
    FufillOrder(purchase);
  }
}
```

The orders are not fulfilled, or consumed. Interestingly, I threw this on `_serviceConnection.OnConnected:`

```
var purchases = _serviceConnection.BillingHandler.GetPurchases(ItemType.Product);
foreach (var purchase in purchases) {
  _serviceConnection.BillingHandler.ConsumePurchase(purchase);
}
```

And that doesn't work either for live products. They are not consumed. (though, again, it does work for `android.test.purchased`).